# Value of polynomial given certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $p (x)=x^5+x^2+1$ let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ be its roots. Let $g (x)=x^2-2$ then the value of $g (x_1)g (x_2)g (x_3)g (x_4)g (x_5)-30g (x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5) $  is? . So   first  I put $x=\sqrt {y+2} $  to create an equation of degree $5$ in terms of$ y $ Put this value in $p (x) $  to get the equation as $(\sqrt {y+2})^5+(\sqrt {y+2})^2+1=0$ Now squaring both sides I get an equation but I dont know what to do next. I also cant find roots of $p (x) $ as it doesnt seem to factor out . Is there any efficient way?

Comment: Try proving $g(x_1)g(x_2)g(x_3)g(x_4)g(x_5) = -p\left(\sqrt 2 \right) p\left(-\sqrt 2\right)$

Comment: This is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you need to compute doesn't require anything complicated. 
So $x_1, \ x_2, \ x_3, \ x_4, \ x_5 $ are roots for the polinomal $p$ so we have:
$g(x_1)g(x_2)g(x_3)g(x_4)g(x_5)=(x_1^2-2)(x_2^2-2)(x_3^2-2)(x_4^2-2)(x_5^2-2)=[(x_1-\sqrt{2})(x_2-\sqrt{2})(x_3-\sqrt{2})(x_4-\sqrt{2})(x_5-\sqrt{2})][(x_1+\sqrt{2})(x_2+\sqrt{2})(x_3+\sqrt{2})(x_4+\sqrt{2})(x_5+\sqrt{2})]$ 
Now from Vieta formulas we have :
$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=0  \ \ ;\  \sum_{i\neq j}x_ix_j=0 \ \ ; \ \sum_{i\neq j \neq k}x_ix_jx_k=-1 \ ; \ x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=1$ Using these results we can substitute them after expansion of respective products in the above square brackets.So we can calculate $g(x_1)g(x_2)g(x_3)g(x_4)g(x_5)$ and later $g(x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5)=g(1)=-1$ And then it's easy to compute $g(x_1)g(x_2)g(x_3)g(x_4)g(x_5)-30g(x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$p(x)=(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})(x-x_{3})(x-x_{4})(x-x_{5})$
find $p(2^\frac{1}{2})$ and $p(-2^\frac{1}{2})$ .
Now multiply both to get $$(x_{1}^2-2)(x_{2}^2-2)(x_{3}^2-2)(x_{4}^2-2)(x_{5}^2-2)=-21 $$ (PLEASE CHECK FOR CALCULATION ERRORS)

Now as for $g(x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}x_{5})$, It's simple $g(1)$ (Multiplaction of Roots)

thus the required answer is $-21+30=9$